# GraphQL Error in Magento 2.4.1: Cannot query field "uid" on type "ConfigurableProductOptionsValues"

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.4.1, graphql, configurable-product-options

I'm having trouble getting the `uid` for my Configurable product options via GraphQL.

Testing with this simplified query:

```
{
    products(filter: { url_key: { eq: "test-product" } }) {
        items {
            sku
            ... on ConfigurableProduct {
                configurable_options {
                    attribute_code
                    values {
                        uid
                        label 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remove `uid` and the query works fine. With it, the response is `Error: Cannot query field "uid" on type "ConfigurableProductOptionsValues".`

Similarly, I have the same issue with 
[ConfigurableProductOptions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/interfaces/configurable-product.html#configProdOptions) and `attribute_uid` (`attribute_id` and `attribute_id_v2` both work, but the docs suggest using `attribute_uid` instead)

Even if I use the exact examples in [the documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/interfaces/configurable-product.html#media-gallery-example), I get the same error.

Is this an environment setup issue? Or maybe the documentation is incorrect? Can't figure it out. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

```
{
  products(filter: { url_key: { eq: "breathe-easy-tank" } }) {
    items {
      id
      __typename
      sku
      name
      stock_status
      ... on ConfigurableProduct {
        configurable_options {
          id
          attribute_id_v2
          use_default
          attribute_code
          label
          position
          values {
            value_index
            label
            swatch_data {
              __typename
              value
            }
          }
          product_id
        }
        variants {
          attributes {
            uid
            label
            code
            value_index
          }
          product {
            id
            name
            sku
            stock_status
          }
        }
      }
      ... on CustomizableProductInterface {
        options {
          __typename
          option_id
          title
          required
          sort_order
          ... on CustomizableFieldOption {
            product_sku
            optvalue: value {
              uid
              max_characters
              price
              price_type
              sku
            }
          }
          ... on CustomizableAreaOption {
            product_sku
            optvalue: value {
              uid
              max_characters
              price
              price_type
              sku
            }
          }
          ... on CustomizableDropDownOption {
            value {
              uid
              option_type_id
              title
              sku
              price
              price_type
              sort_order
            }
          }
          ... on CustomizableRadioOption {
            value {
              uid
              option_type_id
              title
              sku
              price
              price_type
              sort_order
            }
          }
          ... on CustomizableCheckboxOption {
            value {
              uid
              option_type_id
              title
              sku
              price
              price_type
              sort_order
            }
          }
          ... on CustomizableMultipleOption {
            value {
              uid
              option_type_id
              title
              sku
              price
              price_type
              sort_order
            }
          }
          ... on CustomizableDateOption {
            product_sku
            optvalue: value {
              uid
              price
              price_type
              sku
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm still missing the `uid` in the configurable_options values - do you know why the `uid` in particular doesn't work in the configurable_options section?

Comment: Please explain your problem. and what you want to achieve ? And configurable_options uid in the variants->attributes->uid please check it again.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that uid is available in items->variants->attributes->uid, however I'm trying to get uid inside items->configurable_options->values->uid. [According to the docs example here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/interfaces/configurable-product.html#media-gallery-example) this should be possible, but I receive the error in my question above. Thanks!

Comment: this query is wrong https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/interfaces/configurable-product.html#media-gallery-example please refer my answer.